# attaching to an event - but only conditional

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, telerik

I am using kendo schedule widget and want to prevent datsource from reading after crud operations under certain circumstances.
I tryed this by attaching to the `requestStart` event:

```
function subscribeToEvent(e) {

    if (e.condition===condition) {
        var scheduler = $("#scheduleCustomerSchedule").data("kendoScheduler");
        scheduler.dataSource.bind("requestStart", dataSource_requestStart);
    }

}

function dataSource_requestStart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This works but the probem is, that I dont know how die unbind this event **after** it has been executed.
In my case this code prevents `dataSource.Read()` forever, of course.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `requestStart` event and check for the condition in the actual event handler. If that specific condition is only available in the `subscribeToEvent` method, you can pass it using a closure.

```
function subscribeToEvent(e) {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduleCustomerSchedule").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler.dataSource.bind("requestStart", dataSource_requestStart);    
}

function dataSource_requestStart(e) {
    if (e.condition === condition)
        e.preventDefault();
}
```